# How to setup Windows server/IIS for DropkicK deployment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment

I'm testing the Chuck Norris framework's DropkicK for deployment. Currently I'm attempting a simple deployment of a basic web application (no db) on my local IIS but I'm not having much luck.

Are there any required steps I must go through on the server in order to prepare it for DropkicK deployment? I.e. configuring user permissions, configuring IIS, etc.

The error I'm currently getting is (translated from Swedish):

```
System.Security.AccessControl.PrivilegeNotHeldException: The process doesn't have the SeSecurityPrivilege which is required for this operation.
```

when executing this deployment step:

```
securityOptions.ForPath(settings.WebsitePath, fileSecurityConfig => fileSecurityConfig.GrantRead(settings.WebUserName));
```

As I said, I'm trying to deploy to a local IIS with a user account with admin privileges on a non-domain Environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process does not have the security privilege. This may happen regardless of the user if you are operating under the context of UAC.

Best to ensure that the command line is being run with administrative privileges.